# Infinity state&component updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to create simple timer with useEffect and setInterval. In theory, on click it has to:

1. restart cooldown

   ```
   const restartCooldown = () => {
           setCooldownDuration(targetActivity['duration'])
       }
   ```
2. useEffect() will see this and decrease cooldown every second within interval

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
           let interval
           if (props.activity.cooldown) {
               if (cooldownDuration > 0) {
                   if (props.activity.id === 1) {
                       console.log('Activity.js state', cooldownDuration)
                   }
                   interval = setInterval(() => setCooldownDuration(cooldownDuration - 1000), 1000);
               } else {
                   clearInterval(interval)
               }
           } else {
               setCooldownDuration(0)
           }
       });
   ```
3. useEffect() in ActivityProgression.js will get percentage of completion

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
           const interval = setInterval(() => setPercentages((props.totalTime -                props.cooldown) / props.totalTime * 100), 1000);
       })
   ```

4. Then it will be rendered

```
return <ProgressBar animated now={percentages} label={`${percentages}%`} />;
```

But in fact it doesn't work properly, creating infinity multiple renders on click.

[image]

Can you please tell me why? Much much thanks.

[Full code repository to try it yourself](https://github.com/FourZd/react-clicker/)

I tried everything, but it seems that i simply don't understand some react features :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `useEffect` is an array of dependencies. Since you didn't provide any dependencies, it runs every render. Because it updates the state, it causes a re-render and thus runs again, infinitely. Add `[cooldownDuration]` to your use effect like this:

`useEffect(() => {...}, [cooldownDuration])`

This will make the `useEffect` only run when `cooldownDuration` changes.